# iptables target REDIRECT on a bridge without IP

Tags: iptables, firewall, bridge

i have a man-in-the-middle setup like so:

A <---> B <---> C

where A, B and C are computers and the arrows represent ethernet connections.

A has the IP 10.0.0.10,
C has the IP 10.0.0.9

both have a netmask of 255.255.255.0

I am trying to implement a bump-in-the-wire firewall on B using a linux bridge without a configured IP like so:

```
brctl addbr br
brctl addif chlep1
brctl addif chlep2
ifconfig br 0.0.0.0 up
```

in order to grab connections from A to C I configured Iptables on B like so

```
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=1
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -s 10.0.0.10 -d 10.0.0.9 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 40000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 10.0.0.10 -d 10.0.0.9 -j LOG
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.10 -j LOG
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.0.0.10 -j LOG
```

I opened a listening socket on both C and B like so

```
python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM,0)
>>> sk.bind(('0.0.0.0',40000))
>>> sk.listen(1)
>>> conn, addr = sk.accept()
```

then on A I ran

```
python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM,0)
>>> sk.connect(('10.0.0.9',40000))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
>>>
```

checking Iptables for the rule packet count on B I receive

```
[root@ace ~]# iptables -t nat -vL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 269 packets, 64867 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4   240 REDIRECT   tcp  --  any    any     10.0.0.10            10.0.0.9             
redir ports 40000
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  any    any     10.0.0.10            10.0.0.9             
LOG level warning

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 22 packets, 3425 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 76 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 160 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
[root@ace ~]#
[root@ace ~]#
[root@ace ~]#
[root@ace ~]#
[root@ace ~]# iptables -t filter -vL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 456 packets, 28706 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  any    any     10.0.0.10            anywhere             
LOG level warning

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 8 packets, 672 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  any    any     10.0.0.10            anywhere             
LOG level warning

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 240 packets, 19382 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

dmesg is empty.

why am I not hijacking the connection? NOTE: I am able to hijack the connection if I configure the bridge with an IP Address, something I would much rather avoid

Answer (score 0):

Found this after some kernel digging.

the actual iptables REDIRECTing code is implemented in a kernel netfilter hook called [nf_nat_redirect_ipv4](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14-rc6/ident/nf_nat_redirect_ipv4), in it we find this relatively simple code

```
...
/* Local packets: make them go to loopback */
if (hooknum == NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT) {
    newdst = htonl(0x7F000001);
} else {
    struct in_device *indev;
    struct in_ifaddr *ifa;

    newdst = 0;

    rcu_read_lock();
    indev = __in_dev_get_rcu(skb->dev);
    if (indev && indev->ifa_list) {
        ifa = indev->ifa_list;
        newdst = ifa->ifa_local;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();

    if (!newdst)
        return NF_DROP;
}
...
```

let's take this apart

```
...
if (hooknum == NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT) {
    newdst = htonl(0x7F000001);
}
...
```

if our REDIRECT comes from the OUTPUT chain, the destination address of the packet is changer to the loopback address ('127.0.0.1')

```
...
else {
    struct in_device *indev;
    struct in_ifaddr *ifa;

    newdst = 0;

    rcu_read_lock();
    indev = __in_dev_get_rcu(skb->dev);
    if (indev && indev->ifa_list) {
        ifa = indev->ifa_list;
        newdst = ifa->ifa_local;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();
...
```

if we come from another chain (only PREROUTING since we already handled OUTPUT)
we set the destination address of the packet as the address of our local device, our's would be 0

```
 ...
    if (!newdst)
        return NF_DROP;
 }
 ...
```

a zero address is considered an error value, and our packet is sadly dropped :(